# how can we call country code in respect of country

Tags: java, liferay

can any one suggest me how can we call country code in respect of country on selection.
country list is defined under country.xml!
i want when we select india then in ph. no input box country code must apeear auto maticaly +91.
I am just stuck here, and nothing comes in my mind how to do that?

Comment: Show us your codes you tried so far.

Comment: Show us the country.xml. And the code as to how are you populating the country drop-down and what have you tried so far. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal "how to populate a drop-down list in a J2EE application" question.

However, there are bigger problems. Several countries have duplicated country codes. Generally these are recently-formed countries - the results of the Soviet Union, Czechoslovakian and Yugoslavian breakups.

Looking at Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes you can see that Ukraine and Crimea have the same code, as do Monaco and Kosovo. So you can map from country to dial code, but not the other way without a lot of quite detailed logic.